# React native android code push installRelease build fails

Tags: android, gradle, react-native, code-push

I am trying to add code push to my react native app, and followed all steps mentioned in https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push
After doing it, my debug build works fine 
I use :

```
$ ./gradlew installDebug
```

but the release build fails which is given by following command :

```
$ ./gradlew installRelease
```

which gives following error :

```
:app:generateReleaseResources
:app:mergeReleaseResources
:app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Could not list contents of '/Users/jayshah/Documents/testdir/ExampleApp/node_modules/.bin/_mocha'.
```

GitHub
Microsoft/react-native-code-push
react-native-code-push - React Native plugin for the CodePush service.

I use following command to generate the bundle :

```
curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"
```

my react native version is 0.18, 
code push version is 0.16

Answer (score 3):

Turns out this is a problem frequently encountered when upgrading in react native from pre 0.15 to post 0.15 versions.

The react gradle task bundleReleaseJsAndAssets seems to be the culprit.

one can disable it using

```
enabled config.bundleInRelease ?: false
```

in react.gradle or comment the line (no guarantees to work properly though)

```
inputs.files fileTree(dir: reactRoot, excludes: inputExcludes)
```

and manually made bundle file using 
react-native bundle command

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js \
  --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle \
  --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

or curl based command

```
curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"
```